# Search for a match within a match

Tags: regex, match, regex-group

I've seen several "Match within a match" questions but none of the answers fit what I'm trying to do.

Right now I have this string:

```
<td title="Click to view the details" class="alignLeft genericName padding2" style="cursor: pointer;">ACETYLCYSTEINE 200MG/ ML INJ   <br>COLORLESS (IJ)</td>
```

This expression   `;">(.*?(?=<br>))`   will return the following match:

```
ACETYLCYSTEINE 200MG/ ML INJ
```

Now I want to match only the **200MG/ ML INJ**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\S+` to match one or more non-space characters. So this `\S+` after `>` will match the text after the `>` symbol.

```
;">\S+\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<br>)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uP1oU9/2)